# Django deploy errors

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-deployment

I just launched the Django app. As an image, everything is in place, but the form and admin panel do not work. Anyone who knows please help

I get this error when I run the form.
[image]

Let me know if I need to share any code.

model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Form(models.Model):
fname_lname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Ad Soyad")
number = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Nömrə")
send_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Tarix")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Formlar'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Formlar'

def __str__(self):
    return self.fname_lname
```

Comment: Could you add your code for your relevant models?

Comment: Have you run your migrations on the server?

Comment: I don't know how to run

Comment: @DMalan I added model.py

Comment: Run migrate on your server to run the same migrations as you run locally. Otherwise your SQL tables will not be created.

Answer (score 0):

As Marco suggested, once you deploy you should run your migrations since you're probably using a different database. You run migrations same as when in development depending on your platform the following should work:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

just make sure you are on the same directory as the manage.py file. Also remember that you will have to tweak the settings.py file database settings if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

try the commands below:
python manage.py makemigrations --fake
python manage.py migrate --fake

if it donot work, i think you have to delete database and recreate it,

if you need the data you can use python manage.py dumbdata ->data.json
and after you create the new database use python manage.py loaddata data.json